# zIndex on component incorrectly stacking

Tags: css, react-native, z-index

```js
// renderItem
<View>
  <Image source={image} style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 40}} />
</View>
```

```
<View>
    <ImageBackground source={image} style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 50}}/>
    <Image source={image} style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 30}} />
    <Image source={image} style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 20}} />
</View>

<FlatList renderItem={renderItem}/>
```

Idea is that the code above FlatList is fixed in place and image in `renderItem` can change position with scroll.

**Expected Behavior**
renderItem is stacked between zIndex of 50 and 30.

**Current Behavior**
renderItem is always at the back (before zIndex 20 eventhough renderItem has a zIndex of 40)

**What I tried**
For testing, I added another `Image` tag between 50 and 30 in the same file and that seems to be working. So I am guessing the issue only happens when componentizing it. I also tried messing with `elevation` since my target is Android but to no effect.

Any insight would be really helpful - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Working with `zIndex` sometimes happens this. For your case, I suggest you use the props `ListHeaderComponent` and `stickyHeaderIndices` to sticky the header when scrolling the list.

```js
// Some code...

const Header = () => (
  <View style={styles.header}>
    <ImageBackground
      style={styles.imageBackground}
      source={require('./assets/image.png')}
    >
      <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Fixed header</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);

// More code...

return (
  <FlatList
    ListHeaderComponent={Header}
    stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
)
```

I create a [snack on Expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@marcelofreires/stackoverflow-questions-71538522) for you to see the complete example. Just scan the QR Code from your smartphone.